# Issues while writing HTML file

Tags: python, pywikibot

## Problem

Why can't I set this variable html_str equal to the wikisum string variable? Is it a simple syntax error?

## Code

```
import wikipedia
from django.db import models
from django.template import Template, Context
wikisum = wikipedia.summary("Julius Caesar", sentences=2)
print wikisum
html_str = wikisum
Html_file= open("index.html","w")
Html_file.write(html_str)
Html_file.close()
```

#### Thanks!

Btw the error was:

- UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position
  39-40: ordinal         not in range(128)

Comment: How about changing the title... its not a syntax error. Which line is the error on? The solution may be `html_str.encode('utf-8')`.